# small php commercial grade open source project. Suggestions?

Tags: php

Hey guys, I'm learning PHP and I would like to have a look at the source code of a small "commercial grade" PHP project.

Why small? Well because I'm a beginner and big projects such as Drupal or Wordpress are overwhelming right now, aka I don't understand a lot.

Why "commercial grade"? I would like to see if things are done in a different way in comparison to theory, courses and books.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: look into open source MVC frameworks such as codeigniter or kohana. you can learn a lot by looking at those.

Comment: CodeIgniter would definately be a good choice. Look at their user guide and you'll also learn proper code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

At [Google Code](http://code.google.com/) you can search for open-source projects in PHP, browse and download its code and even contribute!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't write off Drupal or WordPress completely because of their complexity. One good way to bite off a small chunk is to look at the code for a [module](http://drupal.org/project/Modules) or [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/). In particular, look for a [popular module](http://drupal.org/project/usage) or [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=plugin&sort=popular) that looks interesting. Since those "popular" modules are in use on a lot of sites, they are likely to be more "commercial grade" than the less popular ones.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
https://github.com/languages/PHP
http://sourceforge.net/directory/language:php/os:windows/freshness:recently-updated/
You will find lots of small projects.